# How to create an over 24 hour voice call in agora for react native?

Tags: node.js, react-native, agora.io

I realized that the voice call token expires every 24 hours. I was wondering how I can implement a call where I can call for over 24 hours? Any help would be appreciated.

mobile

```
 await engine
    .joinChannel(audioRoom.token, audioRoom._id, null, user.audioUId)

engine.addListener('RequestToken', async () => {
});
```

backend node.js

```
export function buildAudioroomToken(name){
    try{
        const token = RtcTokenBuilder.buildTokenWithUid(
            process.env.AGORA_APP_ID,
            process.env.AGORA_APP_CERTIFICATE,
            name,
            uid,
            role,
            privilegeExpiredTs
        );
        return token;
    } catch(err){
        throw new Error(err);
```

Comment: Sounds like a 'red phone wire app for presidents'. whatever. you should be able to create a new audio room before expire and push the user to the new room.

Answer (score 0):

There is a delegate callback when a token will expire soon. You can listen to that callback, fetch a new token when it fires, then renew the token using the SDK.

Those steps are shown in this guide:
https://www.agora.io/en/blog/connecting-to-agora-with-tokens-react-native/